# Is it a good practice to have instance variables which can be derived (computed) from other instance variables?

Tags: oop

I'm new to Object Oriented Programming. I'm working on an application, which takes 2 URLs, fetches their source codes and parses them, and shows results based on some metrics. I'm planning to create a class, make all the metrics it's instance variables, then create 2 instances of this class (1 for each URL), pass the url in the constructor at object initialization and then initialize all the instance variables based on some computation inside the constructor itself. The values of some of the instance variables may depend on the values of other instance variables. Is it a good programming practice to do it the way I'm planning to?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine, as long as you initialize them in the correct order in your constructor. It's not good practice to calculate instance variable values at declaration, but doing so in the constructor should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would at least separate the construction of the object and the initialization, the latter being fetching the source code and calculating the metrics. Fetching is slow and may fail due to external circumstances. Calculation may fail due to unexpected format/content. You would want the setup to be quick and sure to succeed. You could then do the risky stuff by calling a method and if anything fails you will at least have access to the history/state through the already created object. It would make your object more versatile.

Comment: Martin, what is meant by separating the construction and initialization of the object? Do you suggest I don't have any constructor and let the default constructor construct the object and then have a method to actually initialize the fields of the object? In that case, would it make any sense to just create an object without any of it's members initialized?

Comment: I mean you can pass the url to the constructor so the object knows what to do. But don't do you heavy/slow/risky lifting in the constructor code because you will lose the object if an exception is thrown. Which is not necessarily bad but in your case it seems you would like to inspect the downloaded file in case of a failure, which would be a little harder if you lose the object. You would have to pass anything remotely interesting in the exception itself for inspection.